# Max thread numbers

Tags: c#, .net

I can't find anywhere on the internet what is the "formula" behind max thread numbers. I have tested the logic that I have read with cpu, virtual memory and ram memory and in any case I used results were always the same in .NET 4.5. But when I dropped version of .NET Framework to 2.0 I noticed there is a logic that max number of threads you can create by default is 250 per cpu core. But I can't find out what logic lies behind .NET 4.5. I doubt that OS defines it just because it is different result with different .NET versions.

Comment: You don't really want to know. Much more imporant:  Optimal number of threads ≈ number of CPUs

Comment: @HenkHolterman Unless threads are blocked by IO..

Comment: @Eser - yes, that's why we still see much higher numbers. Far from optimal.  `async/await` is a cure.

Comment: Yea but I am not asking about optimal. Yes I want to know. That's the point of my question :)

Comment: The linked dupe talks about maximum. Do read the Raymond Chen article.